# Allow a minus sign in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression, but I do not know how to allow the minus sign. I mean, I would like to allow users to use that sign, but it can also be a positive value without the minus sign.

At the beginning I had this regular expression In JavaScript:

```
 var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
```

I've tried `var regex = /\-[0-9]|\./;`, but it does not work.

This is my JavaScript function:

```
function isNumeric(evt,type)
{
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (type==1)
        var regex = /[0-9]/;
    else if (type==2)
        var regex =  /^-?[0-9]\d*(.\d+)?$/;
    else if (type==3)
        var regex = /[0-9]|\ /;

    /* 13=enter; 9=tabulation; 8et 46 supprim� et sup; 37et 39 fl�che */
    if (theEvent.keyCode == 13 ||
        theEvent.keyCode == 9  ||
        theEvent.keyCode == 8  ||
        theEvent.keyCode == 46 ||
        theEvent.keyCode == 37 ||
        theEvent.keyCode == 39 ||
        (theEvent.keyCode == 19 && type == 3))
    {
        theEvent.returnValue = true;
    }
    else if (!regex.test(key))
    {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault)
            theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it

```
onKeyPress = "isNumeric(event, 2);"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make minus sign optional using `?`:

```
var regex = /^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/;
```

I'm not sure why you have `|\.` which only allows a period in input.

Comment: it is because I can allow number with a full stop as coma

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs that ware valid and some samples that are not?

Comment: I've made an edit of my request

In fact I need to allow all positive or negative decimal numbers it can be -99999999999.99 to 999999999999999.99

Comment: thanks, I've tried it but I can not write minus sign, except that the decimal number works fine

Comment: I guess my function at the beginning is wrong, anyway, thank you for your help